# How to compute the individual contribution of three variables to the difference between their product and an expected value?

Tags: calculus

My topic is related to this post found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142050/effects-of-variables-change-on-total-change-in-a-product-function), although it is quite different.

I am comparing a product of three variables to a threshold value.
To be more specific, let's say we have:
$$ F = A*B*C $$
The range of values $A, B, C$ can take is $[0,1]$. 
$F$ is below a threshold of interest $T$, and I want to determine the relative contribution of each variable ($A, B$ and $C$) to the difference $T-F$.

In two dimensions, I thought I could compute the distance between ($A,B$) and the closest point on the curve $F=T$, and determine which variable contributes the most to this distance. But it does not look like the easiest solution in 3 or more dimensions.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b,c$ be small perturbations in the values of $A,B,C$. Then
$$
(A+a)(B+b)(C+c) \approx ABC + aBC + AbC + ABc
$$
since the omitted terms in the expansion contain products of two small factors. To see that geometrically, imagine a box with sides $A,B,C$.

So a small perturbation in $a$ is magnified by $BC$, etc.

You can interpret that as saying that the "contribution" of $A$ to $ABC$ is $BC$.

That assertion is independent of the threshold value $T$, which may or may not make sense in your application.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I still have to think whether it makes sense to not take into account the threshold.
To avoid problematic cases (such as A >0 , B = 0 and C = 0), do you think of any strategy ? Would it be ok to add a very small number (<<1) to the three variables ?

Comment: You can do anything that makes sense in your application.